# What is the value of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\sin x}$?

Tags: limits

So this is the question in my text book $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\sin x}$$

here what i have done

It can be rearranged as $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$$$\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to0}(1)x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$$$\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}$$$$\Rightarrow1$$

This is what i got. Have done something wrong cause in my text-book the answer is $0$

Here the solution in my text book $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$$$\Rightarrow\lim_{x\to0}(1)x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$$$\Rightarrow0$$
as$$\left|x\sin\frac{1}{x}\right|\le|x|$$

can anyone help me what is wrong

Thanks

Akash

Comment: It is not true that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=1$. For $1/x$ does not approach $0$. The important thing is that $\sin(1/x)$ is bounded, so $x\sin(1/x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: thanks for the explanation nice

Comment: You are welcome. That is something that comes up medium often with questions that involve sine or cosine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your approach, you claim that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{x}}=1$, but in fact the limit $\dfrac{\sin t}{t} \rightarrow 1$ just holds for $t \rightarrow 0$. In your solution $\dfrac{1}{x}$ doesn't satisfy the condition $\rightarrow 0$ but $\rightarrow \infty$.

A correct solution may be the following:

Since $\sin\dfrac{1}{x}$ is bounded and $x \rightarrow 0$, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x \sin\frac{1}{x}=0$.

Comment: @Akash You're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\sin\frac1x}{\sin x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin\frac1x}{\frac{\sin x}x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x\sin\frac1x}1=0.$$

Comment: Which is so because $\sin \frac 1x$ is bounded and $x\sin \frac 1x\to 0$ as $x\to0$

Comment: @Akash: $$-1\le\sin\frac1x\le1\iff-x\le x\sin\frac1x\le x\iff0\le\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\frac1x\le0\iff\lim_{x\to0}x\sin\frac1x=0$$

Comment: The first rightward implication is true for $\;x>0\;$ . Not that it *really* matters in the final outcome as you can work through the squeeze theorem once with $\;x>0\;$ and once with $\;x<0\;$ ...

Answer (score 0):

we need to show that for any positive $\epsilon$ we can provide a positive $\delta$ so that:

$$ \left\lvert \frac{x^2 \, \sin \frac{1}{x}}{\sin x} \right\rvert < \epsilon \,\,\,\,\,\, \Longleftarrow \,\,\,\,\,\,0 < |x| < \delta.$$

assume that $\,\,\delta < \pi$, $\,\,$ so that we can be sure $\sin x \neq 0$. Then, for any $x$ satisfying $0 < |x| < \delta$,

$$ \left\lvert \frac{x^2 \, \sin \frac{1}{x}}{\sin x} \right\rvert \,\,\,=\,\,\, \left\lvert \frac{x^2}{\sin x} \right\rvert \left\lvert \sin \frac{1}{x}   \right\rvert  \,\,\,\leq\,\,\, \left\lvert \frac{x^2}{\sin x} \right\rvert .$$
Therefore, it is good enough to show that
$$  \lim_{x\to 0} \, \frac{x^2}{\sin x} \,\,=\,\,0. $$
But to show that is an easy L'hopital's rule exercise. Then choose $\delta$ the smaller of $\pi$ and the $\delta_1$ from that easy limit.

*Remark - this should work for $\tan x$ or $\sinh x$ in place of $\sin x$. In the case of tangent, require $\,\,\delta < \frac{\pi}{2}.$*